# How do I make input labels appear correctly on iPhone / iPad?

Tags: iphone, css, ipad

I want to make the login labels (at the very top of this page www.plantify.co.uk) appear correctly on iPad and iPhone.

The website is no way responsive, the trouble I am having is that you have to zoom in to focus on the input labels and it looks very messy.

Can any CSS / Responsive legends help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a media query in your CSS like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { // your code goes here }
```

And style the elements you want to look different here.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that although the media queries for just the #topNav dont seem to be picked up at all.